# Help with regex include and exclude

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like some help with regex.

I'm trying to create an expression that will include certain strings and exclude certain strings.

For example:

I would like to include any URL containing mobility `http://www.something.com/mobility/`

However I would like to exclude any URL containing store `http://www.something.com/store/mobility/`

FYI I have many keywords that I'm using to include. Currently I am including like this `/mobility|enterprise|products/i` however I am not finding it able to exclude links that contain other keywords.

Thank you in advance for any help and insight you can provide.

_t

Comment: You must specify the language you are using Regexes from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible to do all this in one regex, but you don't really need to. I think you'll have a better time if you run two separate tests: one for your include rules and one for your exclude rules. Not sure what language you're using, so I'll use JavaScript for the example:

```
function validate(str) {
    var required = /\b(mobility|enterprise|products)\b/i;
    var blocked = /\b(store|foo|bar)\b/i;

    return required.test(str) && !blocked.test(str);
}
```

**If you really want to do it in one pattern,** try something like this:

```
/(?=.*\b(mobility|enterprise|products)\b)(?!.*\b(store|foo|bar)\b)(.+)/i
```

The `i` at the end means case-insensitive, so use your language's equivalent if you're not using JavaScript.

**All that being said,** based on your description of the problem, I think what you REALLY want for this is string manipulation. Here's an example, again using JS:

```
function validate(str) {
    var required = ['mobility','enterprise','products'];
    var blocked = ['store','foo','bar'];
    var lowercaseStr = str.toLowerCase(); //or just use str if you want case sensitivity

    for (var i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
        if (lowercaseStr.indexOf(required[i]) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < blocked.length; j++) {
        if (lowercaseStr.indexOf(blocked[j]) !== -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, but I actually need this use in Google Analytics to create a filter, which doesn't use a language for manipulation, at least that I can get to.

Comment: Nice. The most recent version of your single expression seems to be doing the trick. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 20):

To match a string which must have word from a set of words you can use positive lookahead as:

```
^(?=.*(?:inc1|inc2|...))
```

To not match a string which has a word from a list of stop words you can use negative lookahead as:

```
^(?!.*(?:ex1|ex2|...))
```

You can combine the above two requirements in single regex as:

```
^(?=.*(?:inc1|inc2|...))(?!.*(?:ex1|ex2|...))REGEX_TO_MATCH_URL$
```

[**Rubular link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/fn8sKHk1dN)

Answer (score 3):

Make two regexes one for good and one for bad, and check both? (first the bad, then the good). You can do it with a single regex, but KISS is always a good rule ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle )

I'll add that you need to consider the "ass" principle... `.*ass` matches `ambassador` and `cassette`, so you'll probably want to have a separator (`[./\\]`) before and after each word.
[Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html)